# React useEffect cleanup only on dismount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to trigger an alert on component dismount like so:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if(checked) alert("Hi")
    };
}, []);

...
```

However, the effect doest update the `checked` state when it is changed. This can be fixed however when changing the dependencies from `[]` to `[checked]`. This, however, triggers the alert every render instead of on dismount. But I only want to trigger this on a dismount. How can this be done with react hooks?

Comment: You wrote, "However, the effect doest update the checked state when it is changed."  What does that mean?  Do you want your effect to update the state upon dismount?  Trying to understand what your desired behavior is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the latest value of checked in a ref and then access it from the useEffect.

```
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const checkedRef = useRef(checked);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkedRef.current = checked;
  }, [checked]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (checkedRef.current) alert("Hi");
    };
  }, []);
```

Because refs don't trigger updates, the second useEffect will only run once,
but the first useEffect will make sure checkedRef.current has the latest value.